# The group generated by the union of perfect subgroups is a perfect subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

I was reading a proof and was having a problem - proving the statement above.

Why us the group generated by the union of two perfect subgroups of a group $G$ also perfect? How does this translate to the infinite case?

The proof I was reading was [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/prove-that-every-group-g-has-a-unique-maximal-perfect-subgroup-r-and-r-is?rq=1) To be clear, I have understood the other answer, but also want to know how to prove this statement.

For clarity, a perfect group is a group such that $G=[G,G]=G'$.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "How does this translate to the infinite case?"? Do you mean is the group generated by the union of infinitely many perfect subgroups perfect? The answer to that is also yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are perfect subgroups of $G$ and that $H_1\cup H_2$ generate $G$. Then each element $g$ of $G$ can be written as $a_1b_1a_2b_2\cdots$, where the $a_i$'s belong to $H_1$ and the $b_i$'s belong to $H_2$. Since $H_1$ and $H_2$ are perfect, each $a_i$ and each $b_i$ is a product of commutators (that is, things of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$) and therefore $g$ is also a product of commutators. So, $G=[G,G]$.